# For loop to extract data

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I Have data set with these variables (Branch, Item, Sales, Stock)  I need to make a for loop to extract a data with the following

The same item which has
1-different branches
2- its sales is higher than the stock

and save the result in data frame
The code I used is

```
trials <- sample_n(Data_with_stock,1000)

for (i in  1:nrow(trials)) 
{
if(trials$sales[i] >  trials$stock[i] & trials$item[i] ==  trials$item[i+1] & trials$branch[i] !=  trials$branch[i+1])

{s <-data.frame( (trials$NAME[i])
  ,(trials$branch[i]))
} 

}
```

Comment: How does the variable branch look like, if there are different branches for one item?

Comment: Even with two `==` this `trials$item[i] =  trials$item[i]` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: because the different branches sell the same item in different areas

Comment: no guys I need to make for loop because I need all the answers to be in one data frame the for loop should compare the items in the row and the branches and inside to have i f condition to compare the sales and stock I need to just fix my code please

Answer (score 1):

As you just want to fix your code:

You missed to set one `=`in your code.

Use:

```
trials <- sample_n(Data_with_stock,1000)
# next you need first to define s used in your loop
s <- array(NA, dim = c(1,2)) # as you only save 2 things in s per iteration

for (i in  1:nrow(trials)) {
# but I dont get why you compare the second condition.

if(trials$sales[i] >  trials$stock[i] & trials$item[i] ==  trials$item[i] & trials$branch[i] !=  trials$branch[i+1]) {

s[i,] <- cbind(trials$NAME[i], trials$branch[i])
} else {
s[i,] <- NA # just to have no problem with the index i, you can delete the one with na afterwards with na.omit()
}
```

Comment: look suppose we have 20 branches of pharmacies suppose they sell 100 items I need to find if the item sale is larger than the stock so the other branch can support this item

Comment: So the 100 items are same in all pharmacies they have stock and sales units I need to find the item which has higher sales in stock  so I can send this item from the other branch

Comment: can you please help me finding the items within this selection

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you use **dplyr** library, post installing considering "df" is your dataset, use the below commands for question 1 and 2

#### Question 1

question_one = `df %>% 
               group_by(Item) %>% 
               summarise(No_of_branches = n_distinct(Branch))`

items_with_more_than_one_branch = `question_one[which(question_one$No_of_branches>1)"Item"]`

#### Question 2: Similarly,

question_two = `df %>% 
                group_by(Item) %>% 
                summarise(Stock_Val = sum(Stock), Sales_Val = sum(Sales))`

item_with_sales_greater_than_stock =  `question_two[which(question_two$Sales > question_two$Stock),"Item"]`

Couldn't help but solve without **dplyr**, however suggest, if not used yet, **dplyr** will always be useful for data crunching

Comment: it is not working – Sepa Mostafa 16 hours ago   
look suppose we have 20 branches of pharmacies suppose they sell 100 items I need to find if the item sale is larger than the stock so the other branch can support this item – Sepa Mostafa 16 hours ago   
So the 100 items are same in all pharmacies they have stock and sales units I need to find the item which has higher sales in stock so I can send this item from the other branch – Sepa Mostafa 16 hours ago   
can you please help me finding the items within this selection